# How @Consume from Apache Camel does the mapping in Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, routes, apache-camel, spring-camel

I'm learning about Apache Camel routes in Spring Boot projects and I have a project that does extension from some endpoints. The endpoints are not in this project, only the extension is done here. The extension is done using @Consume from org.apache.camel in this way:

```
@Consume(uri = "direct:products.create.validate.interceptor")
public void executeCreate(RequestWrapper<Product> productWrapper) {
...
}
```

I try to understand how this direct:products.create.validate.interceptor is mapped to an endpoint from another service. Can somebody explain me how this @Consume annotation does the mapping?
Or another example is this:

```
@Consume(uri = "direct:listAccountsPostHook")
public void executeCreate(RequestWrapper<Account> accountWrapper) {
...
}
```

Where should I look to understand how they are mapped? In the controller of the other service? I can't find any example with @Consume. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Consume` annotation in Apache Camel is used to subscribe to a Camel endpoint and consume messages from it. The endpoint can be either a direct endpoint or any other type of endpoint such as a JMS queue or a REST endpoint, depending on your use case.

The endpoint URI, which is specified in the uri attribute of the `@Consume` annotation, determines where the messages are consumed from. In your example, `direct:products.create.validate.interceptor` and `direct:listAccountsPostHook` are both direct endpoints.

In Apache Camel, direct endpoints are in-memory endpoints that allow you to send messages directly to another endpoint in the same JVM. The mapping between the endpoint and the method that consumes the messages is done by Camel's routing engine.
More on Camel Direct endpoints you can read [here](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/direct-component.html).

To understand how the messages are being consumed, you should look at the Camel routes that are defined in your project. In a Spring Boot project, you can define your Camel routes in a `RouteBuilder` class. This is where you would specify the mapping between the direct endpoint and the method that will consume the messages.

For example, if you have a `RouteBuilder` class that looks like this:

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
  @Override
  public void configure() {
    from("direct:products.create.validate.interceptor")
      .to("bean:myBean?method=executeCreate");
  }
}
```

In this example, the direct endpoint `direct:products.create.validate.interceptor` is mapped to the `executeCreate` method in the `myBean` bean. The `?method=executeCreate` part of the to URI tells Camel **to** call the executeCreate method on the myBean bean when a message is received at the endpoint.

So, in short, you should look for the Camel routes in your project that define the mapping between the endpoint and the method that consumes the messages.